# Comparing user input the key:value relationship in a dictionary

Tags: python

This program is a trivia game. I was to show the description (value) of a key:value pair. Then I was the user to guess something. If they guess the correct key for that description I want the program to go to the next description for guessing. If they do not guess correctly, I want the program to give the user another guess.

So far if they guess correctly the program works. If the user guesses incorrectly and the guess is a wrong key, then the program works. If the guess is something random like "ghghghgh" I get the "KeyError".

Console:

```
Tasty And Juicy

What fruit does the above sentence describe per se?gh

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bazinga.py", line 22, in <module>
    if fruits[guess] == fruit:
KeyError: 'gh'

(program exited with code: 1)

Press any key to continue . . .
```

Code:

```
fruits = {

'apple':'tasty and juicy',
'banana':'long and squishy',
'orange':'ripe and yummy'

}


# loops through the values of the dictionary fruits
for fruit in fruits.values():
    print(fruit.title())

    correct = False
    guess = ''

    # guess is base incorrect to start the while loop
    # the while loop goes until the correct guess is declared
    while not correct:
        guess = input("\nWhat fruit does the above setence describe \
per se?")
        if fruits[guess] == fruit:
            print("\nWow what a big brain you got there!")
            corecct = True
        else:
            print("Uh-oh, uh-oh! Guess a again big buy!")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`if guess in fruits` will tell you if the guess is in the dict or not.

```
guess = input("...")
if guess in fruits and fruits[guess] == fruit:
    print("You got it")
else:
    print("Guess again")
```

Or, instead of using `[]` to get the current item in the dict (which, as you found out, will fail if the key isn't there), you can use `.get()`, which returns `None` if the key is not found:

```
if fruits.get(guess) == fruit:
```

Comment: Thank you very much John Gordon! I learned something new today!